# Dynamically request resources of built npm package

Tags: javascript, npm, build, dependencies, vite

Question about building npm packages and ability to dynamically request resources of one package from the other.

Let's say I have a set of images in package A, it also provides JS logic to retrieve them:

```
// In package B
import Component from 'pkg-a'

Component.getImage('foo')
```

and I build it in vite/webpack and later using package B. Package B has package A in dependencies section of 'package.json'

By default the build tool will only link the directly stated images into the /dist folder of package A

But I would like to:

1. have all of images in the /dist folder - that's possible in several ways, like using /public folder;
2. code of package A should accept arguments with image name and return correct image from its dist folder, dynamically - not sure if it's possible;

Is it possible to request only a single picture from package A or do I need to package all the images in BASE64 inside .es.js (this is +30% in size) in package A ?

Answer (score 0):

I would follow the below steps to make it work. I am not pretty sure how it can be done with `vite`(for step 2) but let me share my approach with `webpack` although the baseline idea would be generic.

1. In package `A`, I would create a function(probably in main `index.js`) that accepts the image name as an argument and returns the corresponding image path. It utilizes [dynamic imports](https://javascript.info/modules-dynamic-imports).

   ```js
   export function getImage(name) {
      return import(`./images/${name}.png`);
   }
   ```
2. Next I would configure `webpack` in package `A` to *[copy the images](https://webpack.js.org/plugins/copy-webpack-plugin/)* to the `dist` folder.

   ```js
   // webpack.config.js for package A
   const CopyWebpackPlugin = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
   module.exports = {
     // Other configurations ...
     plugins: [
       new CopyWebpackPlugin([
         { from: 'src/images', to: 'images' },
       ]),
    ],
   };
   ```
3. Finally in package `B`, I would import the `getImage` function from package `A` and use it to request the image(a rough sample you can use as per your framework or requirement)

   ```js
   import { getImage } from 'pkgA';

   async function loadComponent() {
     const imgSrc = await getImage('myRequiredImg');
     const img = new Image();
     img.src = imgSrc.default;
     document.body.appendChild(img);
   }

   loadComponent();
   ```

Comment: thanks for detailed answer @mandy8055! in this case when I am bundling `package B` will it include all the assets from `pkgA/dist` also ?

Comment: You're welcome! When bundling package `B`, if you have set up the dependencies correctly and are importing and using the assets from package `A`, the bundler will include the necessary assets from package `A` in the final build of package `B`.

Comment: However, one thing to note here is bundlers try to optimize the final output by including only the assets that are actually used in package `B`. If you don't explicitly use an asset from package A in package B, the bundler might exclude it from the final build of package B.

Comment: That being said, if you really want to include all the assets from package A, regardless of whether they are used or not, you can **create a separate build process for package A** that copies all assets to its `dist` folder. Then, when package A is added as a dependency to package B, you can copy the assets from package A's `dist` folder to package B's `dist` folder using a plugin or a script during the build process. This way, all assets from package A will be available in package B's output.

Comment: And obviously you can play around with different options to see which one comes out to be useful and performant for your use case.